# Geodataframe to SHP in loop and name of the GDF

Tags: python, shapefile, geopandas, pandas, geodataframe

I am trying to export multiple gdf to shp and name these shp by the gdf name.
I have found this solution

here is my list:

```
maloobchod_list = [maloobchod2006_geom, maloobchod2011_geom, maloobchod2015_geom, maloobchod2016_geom]
```

and here is the code:

```
folderpath=r"E:\folder"
shp = shp

for maloobchod, gdf in enumerate(maloobchod_list, 1):
    filename="gdf_{}.{}".format(maloobchod, shp)
    filepath=os.path.join(folderpath, filename)
    gdf.to_file(filepath, encoding='utf-8')
```

It looks like it saves all the shp from the list, but the names are not the same as the actual gdf from the list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a few issues with your code:

- `shp = shp` This is incorrect, either use `shp = "shp"` of just use ".shp" in the code (as per below)
- `maloobchod` is the loop enumeration value (i.e. 1, 2, etc...), not the name of the gdf. And for what you want, you don't need to use `enumerate`.
- You can't access the name of the original list element without some seriously hacky code, just don't. Use a dict instead.

E.g.

```
maloobchod_dict = {"maloobchod2006": maloobchod2006_geom, "maloobchod2011": maloobchod2011_geom, "maloobchod2015": maloobchod2015_geom, "maloobchod2016": maloobchod2016_geom}
folderpath=r"E:\folder"

for gdf_name, gdf in maloobchod_dict.items():
    filename="gdf_{}.shp".format(gdf_name)
    filepath=os.path.join(folderpath, filename)
    gdf.to_file(filepath, encoding='utf-8')
```